IntelliJ Size of Text
I accidentally changed the text size to be too big and now I'm having trouble changing it back. Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut to undo it or make the text smaller?
I managed to click on the settings, but I can't proceed any further because I can't scroll down or move left or right.
